# Multiple filters of a list via text input with space and comma separators

Tags: string, list, filter

I am using this helpful template: 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_filter_list

but would like to get spaces (and commas if possible) to be read such to allow multiple, separate filters (perhaps being read as ~AND (logical) statements, I'm not sure), as is done in the "Researchers in Agricultural and Biological Sciences" filter on this site: 
http://researchers.uq.edu.au/all-science-journals-classification/agricultural-and-biological-sciences

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I was looking for (many thanks to my friend JKV!):

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, allfound;

    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase().trim().split(/,| /);
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) 
{       allfound = true;
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML.toUpperCase();
        for (var w = 0; w < filter.length; w++) {
            if (a.indexOf(filter[w].trim()) == -1) {
                allfound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        li[i].style.display = allfound?"":"none";
    }
}
</script>
```